# Insertion after deletion in NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I want to clean all the data from a CoreData entity before performing the insertion of newer data. So far what I've tried deletes everything an doesn't allow me to insert newer data, even when using the same context for both operations. Is there a better way to do it? Here's the code I've been implementing. What I do is delete the entity from older records, and then save the context. Then I insert new objects in the context and finally, I just save it. Apparently, after I save it, when I recall the stored data from the view, it returns empty.

```
class DS_Objectives {

let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

func storeObjectives(json: JSON) {

let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
self.dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
self.dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

let request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest.init(entityName: "EducationalObjective")

context.performBlock{
    do{
        let oldObjectives = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as! [NSManagedObject]

        for obj in oldObjectives {
            context.deleteObject(obj)
        }

        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

for (_,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

    var obj : EducationalObjective? = self.findObjective(Int(subJson["IdObjetivoEducacional"].stringValue)!)

    if obj == nil {
        obj = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("EducationalObjective",inManagedObjectContext: context) as? EducationalObjective
        obj!.setValue(Int(subJson["IdObjetivoEducacional"].stringValue), forKey: "id")
    }

    obj!.setValue(Int(subJson["Numero"].stringValue),               forKey: "numero")
    obj!.setValue(Int(subJson["IdEspecialidad"].stringValue),       forKey: "especialidad")
    obj!.setValue(subJson["Descripcion"].stringValue,               forKey: "descripcion")
    obj!.setValue(subJson["CicloRegistro"].stringValue,             forKey: "cicloRegistro")
    obj!.setValue(subJson["Estado"].boolValue,                      forKey: "estado")
    obj!.setValue(self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(subJson["updated_at"].stringValue), forKey: "updated_at")

    for (_,res):(String,JSON) in json["students_results"] {

        var edRes : StudentResult? = self.findStudentResult(Int(res["IdResultadoEstudiantil"].stringValue)!)

        if edRes == nil {
            edRes = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("StudentResult",inManagedObjectContext: context) as? StudentResult
            edRes!.setValue(Int(res["IdResultadoEstudiantil"].stringValue)!, forKey: "id")
        }

        edRes!.setValue(Int(res["IdResultadoEstudiantil"].stringValue), forKey: "id")
        edRes!.setValue(res["Identificador"].stringValue, forKey: "identificador")
        edRes!.setValue(res["Descripcion"].stringValue, forKey: "descripcion")
        edRes!.setValue(res["CicloRegistro"].stringValue, forKey: "cicloRegistro")
        edRes!.setValue(res["Estado"].boolValue, forKey: "estado")
        edRes!.setValue(self.dateFormatter.dateFromString(res["updated_at"].stringValue)!, forKey: "updated_at")

    }
}

do{ try context.save() } catch { print(error) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`context.performBlock` schedules the provided block asynchronously on the managed object context's queue. Since you use this method to schedule deletion but then perform insertion synchronously (and potentially on the wrong queue) you are inserting new objects and then deleting everything.

Comment: Ok, but then how can I prevent the deletion from happening after the insertion?

Comment: You could both actions within the same `performBlock` closure. You could perform each action in it's own `performBlock` closure and those closure will execute in the order in which they are added to the queue. If you know that you're already in the correct concurrency queue you could avoid `performBlock` entirely.

Comment: Sorry, is not working when putting the two inside the performBlock closure